# Sending data byte by byte to Serial Port instead of multiple bytes

Tags: python, serial-port, byte, pyserial

I am trying to send the data calculated on Python to an Arduino but I think below method sends the whole double at one clock cycle. How can I split this into a byte array and send one byte at a time?

```
ser.write(bytes(round(i * double(self.amplitude), 5)))
```

```
ser = serial.Serial(
     port=self.outputFile,
     baudrate=115200,
     parity=serial.PARITY_ODD,
     stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
     bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
)
for i in created_wave:
     ser.write(bytes(round(i * double(self.amplitude), 5)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but I couldn't access the elements of bytearr using bytearr[j] notation but I accessed them with bytearr[j:j+1] notation. It works this way.

```
            ser = serial.Serial(
                port=self.outputFile,
                baudrate=115200,
                parity=serial.PARITY_ODD,
                stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
            )
            for i in created_wave:
                bytearr = struct.pack('f', round(i * float(self.amplitude), 5)) #4 byte
                for j in range(len(bytearr)):
                    ser.write(bytearr[j:j + 1])
```